# Gradle Build path

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying remove from build path this folder (src/main/resources) as you can see en number 1 and 2, and the result is correct in number 3, but when try (refresh gradle project) it back to show again like in the number 1.

I don know if there are some problems with .classpath or something that is reloading the last comfiguration.

I'm using gradle, java 1.7, and STS, etc...

Please help. :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the java plugin applied in your `build.gradle` try to set the resources folders to an empty list:

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = []
```

and then refresh your project in STS.

And I highly recommend to use the buildship plugin for eclipse. It offers the best gradle integration in eclipse. Gradle support in STS is not maintained anymore I think.